# How to make JavaFx 15.0.1 work with IntelliJ, troubleshoots not working?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I know, there are some related questions here, but none of these work in my case, so I have to post this newly.

The following well-known error occurs if I try to run the sample fx-application with java 15.0.1 and javafx 15.0.1:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found

The jetbrains-troubleshoot ([link to the troubleshot](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#troubleshoot)) says:

> The path to the JavaFX library in the VM options field in the run configuration is likely to be incorrect. Make sure that the path is valid and try again.

I already thourougly checked my vm-options and paths to the fx-locations but cannot find any errors.
Here my vm-Options in IntelliJ's Run/Debug confiurations dialog:

```
-cp %JAVA_HOME% --module-path "%JAVA_FX%" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
```

whereas the system environment variable JAVA_FX points to my installation location of javafx:

```
JAVA_FX=C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib
```

Besides, I followed all necessary steps, which are described by jetbrains [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#create-project).

Comment: what happens when you hard-code the module path (vs. using the environment variable) in the vm options? Just a blind guess, but more often than not there's some tiny detail that's wrong .. so ...

Comment: yes, that's what I think too, it must be some tiny but develish detail ;-), so I appreciate any comments or ideas :-). I already tried to hardcode the module path, however with the same result. I use windows 10, could it be a UAC issue, cause all my java-libs are located under system drive c:?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: I did it exactly like described in the section "JavaFx and IntelliJ/Modular from IDE" in the provided link openjfx.io/openjfx-docs, but it results in the same error...

Comment: Latest update: I reported the problem to IntelliJ-support and they opened a new internal request (#3003595). I will report, if they have a solution ...